# The reason that the plot is not symmetrical after rotation

Tags: plotting

Now I am a little confused about the reason my plot seems to be not symmetrical. I believe the plot should like several circles while it is not.
Here is my code. And the picture looks like this.

```
DensityPlot[BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20},
```

Mesh -> False] 
[image]

And when I expand the region, it seems to be worse:

```
DensityPlot[BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200},Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

I wonder if anyone knows the reason why it looks like that?

Answer (score 6):

The Bessel functions are highly oscillating and

```
DensityPlot[BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200}, 
 Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

shows you that the triangle grid on which this is plotted is much too coarse. The grid cannot capture details, if the maximum edge length of each triangle is not smaller than "half the wavelength".

Try

```
DensityPlot[BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

For the second plot, the number of buckles within the plot range is so large that we have to crank up the `PlotPoints` even more:

```
DensityPlot[
 BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) states:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Animate[
 DensityPlot[
  BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]
  , {x, -20, 20}
  , {y, -20, 20}
  , Mesh -> False
  , PlotPoints -> k
  , PlotLabel -> StringTemplate["PlotPoints->``"][k]
  ]
 , {k, 2, 50, 1}
 ]
```

[image]